# apply a function to data frame according to the i'th element of a list in R

Tags: r, loops, sorting, apply

I would like to achieve the following result by using only apply and avoiding loops:

dA is a data frame, I would like to order (sort) specific elements of each row of dA. The elements I want to sort are listed in a list.

So for instance:

```
Elements[[1]] = c(1,3,4,8)

Elements[[2]] = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,9)
```

So the result should be a list dA_new in which in the first row elements {1,3,4,8} are sorted and in the second row elements {2,3,4,5,6,7,9} are sorted.
Since Elements has many rows I would like to avoid a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `dA` (or a significant subset of it) and describe better the desired output based on `dA`.

Comment: dA[1,]=c(900, 800, 1000, 100, 1100, 600, 200, 1200, 1300, 400), dA[2,] = c(400, 200, 100, 900, 700, 300, 600, 1000, 1100, 500), so the final result should be elements 1,3,4,8 of dA sorted, giving dA_new[[1]] = c(100, 900, 1000, 1200) and so forth for each row of dA. dA_new is a list because the number of elements to be sorted are different for each row

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I got the question.
You have to use Map (just a multidimensional version of lapply) to apply to each column of the dataframe, each element of the list in order to filter the proper rows.
Then you have to use apply on the resulting list to sort

```
a=c(900, 800, 1000, 100, 1100, 600, 200, 1200, 1300, 400)
b = c(400, 200, 100, 900, 700, 300, 600, 1000, 1100, 500)
dA<-data.frame(rbind(a,b))
dA


Elements<-list()
Elements[[1]] = c(1,3,4,8)
Elements[[2]] = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,9)

lapply(Map("[",as.data.frame(t(dA)),Elements),sort)
```

Comment: This uses a transposed version of the df specified - a and b should be rows, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are looking for...

```
mapply(function(x,y) sort(x[y]), as.data.frame(t(dA)), Elements)

$`1`
[1]  100  900 1000 1200

$`2`
[1]  100  200  300  600  700  900 1100
```